# call onActivityResult android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have the next code:

```
class Printer{
Activity activity;
public Printer (Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    initializeBluetooth();
}

public boolean initializeBluetooth() {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, activity.getString(R.string.notSupportedBluetooth), 3000);
        toast.show();
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            activity.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println(resultCode);
    if (resultCode == 0) {
        System.out.println("one");
    } else {
        System.out.println("two");
    }
}}
```

The problem is the onActivityResult, i know it can not be called because the class is not an Activity, so how can i check if the user clicked yes or no to the bluetooth request with out turning my class to an activity??? `activity.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);`
Thank you

Comment: Where and how is this class used?

Comment: I use this class as an API, it is suppouse to call the class and make the request for turn on the bluetooth, in case the user do not accept the request, i have to show something

Comment: you could call a method inside initializeBluetooth() right before you return...I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish though

Comment: The activity.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0); shows a message dialog request to turn on the bluetooth of the celphone, i need to know if the user accept that request or decline it

Comment: This is a good argument for using the @Override decorator freely.  If you had put "@Override" in front of onActivityResult(), you would have discovered the problem at compile time.  Bottom line:  It's the *activity* that gets the callback to onActivityResult(), your Printer class would never have received it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing this? Just include all of the bluetooth functionality in the `Activity` class... there is no need to create a separate class for this.

Anyway, just copy and paste your `onActivityResult` code into your `Activity` file:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println(resultCode);
    if (resultCode == 0) {
        System.out.println("one");
    } else {
        System.out.println("two");
    }
}
```

It makes no sense to include `onActivityResult` in your `Printer` class, as `onActivityResult` will be called for the *calling `Activity`*.